# Properly document a constructor passed as parameter

Tags: python, documentation, docstring, google-style-guide

I'm trying to figure out what is the properly way to document a function that receives a class constructor as parameter . I'm using Google style docstring.

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

def my_func(param1, class_constructor):
"""Example function.

Args:
    param1 (int): ...
    class_constructor (???): My class constructor.
"""
    class_instance = class_constructor()
    ...

my_func(12, MyClass)
```

Comment: What's a "class constructor" in this context? Isn't it just a class?

Comment: Its just a class indeed

Comment: Actually this should probably accept just any callable - no reason to restrict it to a `class` object (unless something else in the code requires it to be a class but that doesn't seem to be the case in the snippet).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know with what to replace ??? in your example. As pointed out in the comments of the original question, your `class_constructor` argument should in fact be a class, so the appropriate type would be `type` (ignoring old style classes).

Comment: Since the same code would work with just any callable and using either a plain function as a factory or a classmethod as an alternate constructor are common patterns, I'd document it as  "a callable returning an object".

Comment: Any object with a `__call__` method is callable. There is a builtin called `callable` that checks for the existence of this method, but there is no overall type of that kind (correct me if I'm wrong). Callable objects can be functions, class instances and probably others I'm not thinking of right now.